# Docker for Flask application is not running -connection error

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, flask

I am running a Flask application in docker and I cannot get it started.
I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.

What happens is that I build the image,  I run and then I do in my browser at 127.0.0.1:5000 and get a connection error.

I build the image :

```
sudo docker build -t flask-image:latest .
```

Then I run:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name flask_try flask-image:latest
```

Now, when I go in a browser to `127.0.0.1:5000`, the connection fails.

Then I do `sudo docker ps` and I get :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND           CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
c161375d3a7a   flask-image:latest   "python app.py"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   flask_try
```

I did also :

```
sudo docker logs flask_try
```

Here I get some warnings related to a library I import, that is all. It seems to me that some warnings are not a problem. Does someone think otherwise ?

I did also :

```
sudo docker exec -it flask_try  /bin/bash
```

And I get the error "container is not running" :

```
Error response from daemon: Container b20b12ac58d461e5e60c5da1873585f03ba2c8c7a2c3d3408e4e46882e2f69d3 is not running
```

Here is what my Dockerfile looks like :

```
FROM python:3.7 as alias_one

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    python3.7 \
    python3-pip \
    wget \
    apt-transport-https \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    bash \
    perl \
    publicsuffix 

RUN mkdir /local/
WORKDIR /local/

(... install libs with wget, run installation shells etc. ...)

# second image:
FROM python:3.7

# new workdir
WORKDIR /flask_app_dir
ADD . /flask_app_dir

ARG SPACY_VERSION=2.3.4

COPY ./dir1 /flask_app_dir/dir1
COPY ./__init__.py /flask_app_dir/__init__.py
COPY ./config.py /flask_app_dir/config.py
COPY ./app.py /flask_app_dir/app.py


COPY ./requirements.txt /pynlg_root/requirements.txt

COPY --from=alias_one /local/ /local/

# I declare here a path I need
ENV PATH /local/bin:/local/cmd:$PATH

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install spacy==${SPACY_VERSION}
RUN python -m spacy download fr_core_news_lg
RUN pip install six

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

The file requirements.txt contains one line :

`flask==1.1.2`

My application (file app.py) is this.
Note: this Flask application works well without Docker.

```
# encoding: utf-8
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

( ... imports ...)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_request():
    ( ... run some code that does something ...)
    return_dict = {
        "key1":"value1"
        "key2":"value2"
    }
    return return_dict

if __name__ == '__main_':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Any help is welcome !

Comment: How doesn't it work?  How do you try to connect to it, and what response do you get?

Comment: I build the image, then I run : `sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name flask_try flask-image:latest`. Do I need to do something else ? I saw also  'sudo docker start <container_name>`. Do I have to use it ? After run, if I do `sudo docker <container_name> ps`, I can see the image associated to the container, as I wrote above.

Comment: The `docker ps` output you included indicates the container is running; that `docker run` command seems correct (and you do not need to separately start the container).  When you say "it does not work", what problem are you having?

Comment: I updated the answer : When I try to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000, I get "connection fails" in the browser. If I try that with Flask and no Docker, it works, and I get my result in the browser. I understood that the docker container stops when the parsing in the Flask app is over, is this the reason that I see nothing in the browser ? If this is the case, how can I test that the application works and returns the good result ? Making an echo ?

Comment: Now one more thing : when I run, it stops at a certain moment and I get no errors, just warnings. Moreover, I thought it is not running, because I saw other console sceenshots where it was written `<container_name> Running on <host>:<port>`. And I do not have this, is that a problem?

Comment: @David Maze: I bother you with another question : I create the file `local` in which I put things and then I make another image for Flask this time and I do `COPY --from=alias_one /local/ /local/`. Did I have to do : COPY --from=alias_one /local/ `/flask_app_dir/local/` ? In this case, if I use the path `/flask_app_dir/local/` in app.py, how shall I use it ? In fact I give it as an argument to a function. Shall I write `/local` only? By the way, I cannot see this file as if it were not created.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated my question: if I do this, after running : `sudo docker exec -it flask_try  /bin/bash` I get mesage that the container is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. In fact I had to delete from my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

And replace it just with :

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

This allowed to see the result in the browser.